# Form does not submit data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, forms

I have a form that has a few fields that should populate to my database which it doesn't. I am unsure why this is. I defined the parameters which fixed another error but my data is not being stored. My table name is users.

My controller:

```
 Class LandlordPageController < ApplicationController
      before_action :get_user

      def get_user
        @user = current_User
      end

      def index
      end

      def show
      end

      def create
          @user = User.new(user_params)
          @user.save
          redirect_to profile_page_index_path
      end

      private

        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:address, :cityResiding, :ssn, :birthDate, :gender, :phoneNumber)
      end
end
```

My form:

```
<%= form_for :user do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%=f.label :address, 'Current Address' %><br/>
      <%=   f.text_field :address, :required => 'required' %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%=f.label :cityResiding, 'Current City' %><br/>
      <%=   f.text_field :cityResiding, :required => 'required' %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%=f.label :phoneNumber, 'Phone Number'%><br/>
      <%= f.telephone_field :phoneNumber, maxlength: 15, :required => 'required' %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%=f.label :gender, 'Gender'%><br/>
      <%= f.select :gender, ['',' Male', 'Female', 'Other','Prefer Not to Answer']%>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%=f.label :birthDate, 'Birth Date'%><br/>
      <%= f.date_select :birthDate, order: [:month, :day, :year], :required => 'required'%>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%=f.label :ssn, 'Social Security Number' %><br/>
      <%=   f.text_field :ssn, maxlength: 9 %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Submit Information" %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

log:

```
Started GET "/landlord_page" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-06 17:59:58 -0500
Processing by LandlordPageController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering landlord_page/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered landlord_page/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 98ms (Views: 88.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started POST "/landlord_page" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-11-06 18:00:06 -0500
Processing by LandlordPageController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"98tUidqprFyTG8ZC/tV9TRDIVlV0I+ocnQfKTUDqorlS+JMFHtaCWz69EwBvH5MrHhnRbg93m695//Z1I5xt3A==", "user"=>{"address"=>"1", "cityResiding"=>"1", "phoneNumber"=>"1", "gender"=>" Male", "birthDate(2i)"=>"11", "birthDate(3i)"=>"6", "birthDate(1i)"=>"2016", "ssn"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit Information"}
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/profile_page
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**EDIT:** My form does submit data but this error is being thrown on save

```
NoMethodError in LandlordPageController#create
undefined method `save' for #<Array:0x0000000d883a08>
```

Comment: what does it show in the logs? where is the form ?

Comment: Does your model require any other fields? Providing your table structure would also be helpful. On first glance I cannot see any mistake.

Comment: Potentially you may be getting validation errors but you appear to be ignoring these by doing `redirect_to profile_page_index_path` irrespective of whether or not @user.save is successful. As a quick test try `puts @user.errors` after `@user.save` to check for validation errors.

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with validation errors, but for better diagnostics, change your `create` method to do `@user.save!`, which will cause errors to be thrown rather than silently consumed.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I did not know that is a thing, that sure helps out regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `new` I went with `update` and removed the `save`, because the new already executed saving the parameters and save was trying to save nil parameters. I was not creating a *new* user but meaning to add new parameters to an existing user. This is why the error occured. The full final code is below.

```
  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      if User.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to profile_page_index_path, notice: 'Landlord application successfully submitted.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else       
        format.html { redirect_to profile_page_index_path, notice: 'Landlord application was not successfully submitted.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: `create` should create the `User` not update it. That's what the `update` method/route is for

Comment: @CarlMarkham that is where I went wrong. I was meaning to update the existing user with those parameters.

Comment: Your code still won't work. You should be triggering the `update` method on the instance of the model `@user.update`

Comment: Please look at my answer. It shows you how to do this the correct way. Also, your code doesn't let the user know what went wrong if there is an error. Would be useful for them to know if the error is caused by them or not. You also don't show the error if it is an xhr request

Answer (score -1):

As has been said, the issue is probably validation errors.
If you mean to update the user, you will need to use the `update` method instead and pass the user to the form

`form_for @user`

That will send a `PATCH` request to the `update` method on the controller once the form is submitted.

```
def update
  @user.update user_params
  if ! @user.valid?
    flash[:error] = @user.errors.full_messages
  end

  redirect_to profile_page_index_path
end
```